# Magento 2.3: One or more indexers are invalid

Tags: magento2.3

We are facing a problem with Magento 2.3 in indexers we tried a lot to fix it without any solution

You could see from the next screenshot that Reindex Required
[image]

We tried to edit our Cron job to fix the problem without any solution, below screenshot from our cron job
[image]

Could anyone help us in this issue, considering that we are using cpanel and don't have any access on SSH, we are using Magento 2.3, and we using php 7.2

Thank you in advance

Comment: could you see `update.cron.log`,`setup.cron.log`, `indexer.cron.log` and `magento.cron.log` in your /var/log folder ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the sample cron setup from the [official doc page](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html) with three cron jobs running, no need for the additional `indexer:reindex` as it's already part of `cron:run`.

Make sure they're scheduled to run every minute. If the interval is longer, e.g. every five minutes, the indexer scripts will be missed and a ‘One or more indexers are invalid‘ message will appear in the admin area.

```
#~ MAGENTO START
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END
```